# How to stop deleting related foreign key values when deleting primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

The problem is following: I have three related tables, one storing Clients info, second storing SubscriptionTypes and third Payment.

When Payment is created, consisting of ClientId and SubscriptionId, client with proper Id is updated with proper subscription.

The issue which I cant handle is when I delete Client, also all payments associated with this client are deleted. I suspect it may be related to CascadeDeleting, although cannot really find how to solve that one.

This are my models:

```
public class Payment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public Subscription Subscription { get; set; }

    // More properties...     
}

public class Client    
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }        

    public int? SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public Subscription Subscription { get; set; }

    // More properties...
}

public class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen in the database?  If you have a `Payment` for `ClientId` 5, and there *is no* `Client` with an `Id` of 5, how useful is that data?  It sounds like what you want is called a "soft delete", where you keep the data but have a property called something like `IsDeleted` and in your application you filter on that property where appropriate.

Comment: Oh, okey I see the point. So in that case, should I redefine whole delete method in my controller, working only in a way that it sets value IsDeleted to true, and doesn't change anything in Db (doesn't delete anything?) Is that a good solution?

Comment: _Soft delete_, or _logic deletion_ as I'd known it until now, is a good option to make the user think they deleted data when actually you are just hiding it from them. This allows to keep it and easily restore it if the user wants it back. Of course, you should consider whether or not to include softly-deleted results in a `SELECT`. Maybe a regular user has them hidden, while an administrator can see them and restore them.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've never really considered this solution, by I think thats what Im gonna do

Comment: Going back to your problem, it is indeed because of a cascade delete. If you want to really delete records and you still want a `Payment` to persist even without a `Client`, you will have to turn off the cascade delete option. Make sure to update the `Payment` so that its `Client` foreign key is `NULL`, after setting it as a nullable field (a column which accepts `NULL` values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the column_constraint page on [MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-column-constraint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT }
>   Specifies what action happens to rows in the table that is altered, if those rows have a referential relationship and the referenced row is deleted from the parent table. The default is NO ACTION.